# Using DISTINCT with Multiple Condtional Aggregations (Annotate)

Tags: python-2.7, distinct, annotate, django-1.11, conditional-aggregation

Python: 2.7
Version: Django 1.11

Hello,

I am having issues with using conditional aggregation with COUNT DISTINCT in my Django query.
The problem is when I join a separate table, my distinct count on the IDs does not seem to work.
I have a query where I do a conditional aggregation to count days and sum minutes based on other attributes.

In the example below, we want to query for two things at the same time:

- The count of the 'number of sunny days logged' for each dog.
- The total amount of time we walked each dog

(Please bear with me on the example. I tried simplifying the models)

**Models:**

```
from django.db import models

class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class DailyLog(models.Model):
    dog = models.ForeignKey(Dog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_sunny = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class WalkSession(models.Model):
    daily_log = models.ForeignKey(DailyLog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    minutes_walked = models.IntegerField()
```

**Populate Data via Migration:**

```
 d1 = Dog.objects.create(name="Fido")
 d2 = Dog.objects.create(name="Fido2")
 d3 = Dog.objects.create(name="Fido3")

 dl1 = DailyLog.objects.create(dog=d1, is_sunny=True)
 dl2 = DailyLog.objects.create(dog=d2, is_sunny=False)
 dl3 = DailyLog.objects.create(dog=d3, is_sunny=False)

 WalkSession.objects.create(daily_log=dl1, minutes_walked=100)
 WalkSession.objects.create(daily_log=dl1, minutes_walked=200)
 WalkSession.objects.create(daily_log=dl2, minutes_walked=50)
 WalkSession.objects.create(daily_log=dl3, minutes_walked=999)
```

**Python Console:**

Simple check for the minutes summed.

```
   DailyLog.objects.all().values('dog__name').annotate(total_minutes_walked=Sum('walksession__minutes_walked'))

Result: <QuerySet [{'dog__name': 'Fido', 'total_minutes_walked': 300},
     {'dog__name': 'Fido2', 'total_minutes_walked': 50},
     {'dog__name': 'Fido3', 'total_minutes_walked': 999}]>
```

Simple check on the number of sunny days logged.

```
DailyLog.objects.all().values('dog__name').annotate(sunny_days_logged=Count(Case(When(is_sunny=True, then='id'), distinct=True)))

Result: <QuerySet [{'dog__name': 'Fido', 'sunny_days_logged': 1},
     {'dog__name': 'Fido2', 'sunny_days_logged': 0},
     {'dog__name': 'Fido3', 'sunny_days_logged': 0}]>
```

Query that joins the DailyLog table and WalkSession with conditional aggregation.

**We now see that sunny days logged is '2'. We expected this to be '1'.**

```
DailyLog.objects.all().values('dog__name').annotate(total_minutes_walked=Sum('walksession__minutes_walked'), sunny_days_logged=Count(Case(When(is_sunny=True, then='id'), distinct=True)))

Result: <QuerySet [{'dog__name': 'Fido', 'total_minutes_walked': 300, 'sunny_days_logged': 2},
     {'dog__name': 'Fido2', 'total_minutes_walked': 50, 'sunny_days_logged': 0},
     {'dog__name': 'Fido3', 'total_minutes_walked': 999, 'sunny_days_logged': 0}]>
```

I looked at the queries generated and it seems that the DISTINCT option is dropped when we use CASE WHEN.

```
SELECT dogwalker_dog.name,
        SUM(dogwalker_walksession.minutes_walked) AS 'total_minutes_walked',
        COUNT(CASE
              WHEN dogwalker_dailylog.is_sunny = true THEN dogwalker_dailylog.id ELSE NULL END) AS 'sunny_days_logged'
    FROM dogwalker_dailylog
    INNER JOIN dogwalker_dog
    ON dogwalker_dailylog.dog_id = dogwalker_dog.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dogwalker_walksession
    ON dogwalker_dailylog.id = dogwalker_walksession.daily_log_id
GROUP BY dogwalker_dog.name
```

- DISTINCT was missing from COUNT.
- COUNT(**DISTINCT** CASE
                WHEN dogwalker_dailylog.is_sunny = true THEN dogwalker_dailylog.id ELSE NULL END) AS 'sunny_days_logged'

Documentation does say that multiple aggregations could show wrong results.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations
I was attempting to use the DISTINCT parameter to help with this issue.

- Why does DISTINCT get dropped when using CASE WHEN?
- Would it be best to separate the queries instead of trying to calculate multiple things in one query?

Answer (score 1):

My mistake on the brackets and missing option output_field option.

The statement below yields the correct count of Sunny days for each dog.

```
DailyLog.objects.all().values('dog__name').annotate(total_minutes_walked=Sum('walksession__minutes_walked'), sunny_days_logged=Count(Case(When(is_sunny=True, then='id'), output_field=IntegerField()), distinct=True))
```